# bidirection sync between linux and novell

Tags: linux, sync, raspberry-pi

i am at a stage of my PhD where the data and script amount is so large, that simple copy paste file transfer leads to confusion. I would like to synchronize my laptop (debian testing) with the data stored on a novell server.
I tried bittorrent sync but it stopped synchronizing some folders and the projects folder structure is not conserved.

I would like to have a solution like the following:
A local encrypted copy of my data on an usb device (~ 100 Gb). Whenever i work somewhere else than at work, i use the usb drive and the directory structure always stays the same. When i return home or to work, i plug the usb drive into my computer (at work) or raspberry (at home) and synchronize the data while having a coffee.

Is that possible without spending the rest of my PhD (1/2 year) hacking around ? And if so, where to start ?

Comment: What kind of Novell server are we talking about? Are you connecting over NCP via the Novell Client, or over CIFS via Samba?

Comment: I connect via NPC. And i am not the owner of the server

Comment: Have you tried `rsync`?

Comment: no, but i will give it a try. THX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rsync, already mentioned in the comments, may be a good choice. rsync for NetWare can be found there: http://www.novell.com/developer/ndk/rsync_for_netware.html